# Can't find attributes using StAX

Tags: attributes, stax

I have a simple XML file:

```
`<?xml: version = "1.0" ?>
<Company>
    <Employee category = "technical">
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <ContactNo>123456789</ContactNo>
    </Employee>
    <Employee category = "non-technical">
        <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <ContactNo>1234567898</ContactNo>
    </Employee>
</Company>`
```

Now, I have to parse the XML using StAX, but I can't get the attributes.
My code is:

```
 `public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, FileNotFoundException {
    XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    Reader reader = new FileReader("Company.txt");
    XMLStreamReader xmlsr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(reader);
    while (xmlsr.hasNext()) {
        switch (xmlsr.next()) {
            case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                System.out.println("START_ELEMENT");
                System.out.println("Qname:" + xmlsr.getName());
                break;
            case XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT:
                System.out.println("END_ELEMENT");
                System.out.println("Qname:" + xmlsr.getName());
        }

    }
}`
```

When I start to read the element I have to check if it has an attribute in it using a simple IF function. if it has an attribute, I will use :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < xmlsr.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
String attributeName = xmlsr.getAttributeLocalName(i);
String attributeValue = xmlsr.getAttributeValue(i);
System.out.println("Attribute value for " + attributeName + " = " + attributeValue);
}
```

But, I do not know  where exactly to put the IF function and how to check it.
Please, can someone insert the code of the IF function.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, so I hope you got the answer by yourself :D

But in case you didn't, the attributes are stored in the START_ELEMENT. This means that the correct place to add your Attribute printing code is in the `case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT` as you can see below.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, FileNotFoundException {
        XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        Reader reader = new FileReader("Company.txt");
        XMLStreamReader xmlsr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(reader);
        while (xmlsr.hasNext()) {
            switch (xmlsr.next()) {
                case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
                    System.out.println("START_ELEMENT");
                    System.out.println("Qname:" + xmlsr.getName());

                    int numberOfAttributes = xmlsr.getAttributeCount();
                    if (numberOfAttributes > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAttributes; i++) {
                            String attributeName = xmlsr.getAttributeLocalName(i);
                            String attributeValue = xmlsr.getAttributeValue(i);
                            System.out.println("Attribute value for " + attributeName + " = " + attributeValue);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT:
                    System.out.println("END_ELEMENT");
                    System.out.println("Qname:" + xmlsr.getName());
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```